# Executing external programs via commandline in a Grails application

Tags: java, command-line, grails

I am attempting to create a Java source file which will interface with my Grails application.  When a certain action is performed, I want this Java file to execute a program via commandline.  I am attempting to do this via the Runtime.getRuntime().exec() command, however I keep getting an error about the Runtime object being undefined.  Is it not possible to get a handle on this object through Grails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Java 5 or later you are better off using `ProcessBuilder` rather than `Runtime.exec`. See [here](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) for more information.